# How to substitute and simplify an expression in sympy?

Tags: sympy

I want to substitute expression

```
(k*x_2 + m)/(x_2 + 1) + (k*x_1 + m)/(x_1 + 1)
```

with

```
x_1 + x_2 = -(2*k*m-8)/k**2
x_1 * x_2 = m**2/k**2
```

and simplify it, which should have following result:

```
8*(k + m)/(k**2 - 2*k*m + m**2 + 8)
```

I have tried `.subs({x1+x2: blahblah, x1*x2: blahblah})`. Indeed, it does substitute some `x1+x2` and `x1*x2` with `blahblah`, but it still remains some `x1+x2` in the expression. How to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to .simplify() your expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the definition of x1 and x2 had something wrong. I get the desired result using what was shown:

```
>>> a = (k*x_2 + m)/(x_2 + 1) + (k*x_1 + m)/(x_1 + 1)
>>> b = collect(collect(cancel(a), m), k)
>>> b.subs({x_1 + x_2: -(2*k*m - 8)/k**2, x_1*x_2: m**2/k**2}).simplify()
8*(k + m)/(k**2 - 2*k*m + m**2 + 8)
```

Another way to think of this problem is that it requires `x_1` and `x_2` to be eliminated from `a` given the relationships you define. So if we solve the coupled relationship for `x_1` and `x_2` and substitute those into `a` we will have the desired result:

```
>>> e2  # = Eq(x_1 + x_2 , (-2*k*m + 8)/k**2)
x_1 + x_2 == (-2*k*m + 8)/k**2
>>> e3
x_1*x_2 == m**2/k**2
>>> x1x2 = solve((e2,e3),x_1,x_2,dict=True)  # two solutions are given
>>> a.subs(x1x2[0]).simplify()  # use either solution; the result is the same
8*(k + m)/(k**2 - 2*k*m + m**2 + 8)
```

Comment: I had considered solving for `x_1` and `x_2`, but decided to not go that route when I saw how complicated the solutions were. That technique definitely won't work in general.

Comment: I don't think my variables were defined incorrectly. I did have `x1 = x_1` and `x2 = x_2`. But note my comment, where adding `2` to both sides made it work.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't try `expr.cancel().collect(k).collect(m)` which really works well!

Answer (score 0):

SymPy only substitute expressions for expressions if it can find them exactly (with a few little additions like matching `2*x` against `4*x`).

You'll need to rewrite the expression to have those terms like you want. `cancel` will put everything under one denominator, and `collect` will let you convert `m*x_1 + m*x_2` into `m*(x_1 + x_2)` in that expression, so that you have `x_1 + x_2`. In short:

```
>>> a = (k*x_2 + m)/(x_2 + 1) + (k*x_1 + m)/(x_1 + 1)
>>> b = collect(collect(cancel(a), m), k)
>>> b
(k*(2*x_1*x_2 + x_1 + x_2) + m*(x_1 + x_2 + 2))/(x_1*x_2 + x_1 + x_2 + 1)
>>> b.subs({x1 + x2: -(2*k*m - 8)/k**2, x1*x2: m**2/k**2})
(k*(2*m**2/k**2 + (-2*k*m + 8)/k**2) + m*(x_1 + x_2 + 2))/(1 + m**2/k**2 + (-2*k*m + 8)/k**2)
```

This didn't seem to work completely, which I have opened a bug for https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7475.

Comment: A workaround seems to be to do another `subs({x1 + x2 + 2: -(2*k*m - 8)/k**2 + 2})`. You can then call `cancel` on the result to get your desired `8*(k + m)/(k**2 - 2*k*m + m**2 + 8)`.